# Header not Displayed until Hovered Over

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Website in question: http://wp.granitebayit.org/

For certain people the whole header/nav section of this website is invisible until hovered over.  I've been able to reproduce this problem in chrome by visiting the website and refreshing the page with Shift + F5.

When invisible, the only thing on the website is the video background.

Any suggestions appreciated.  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it's a problem with your the poster image attribute in the video tag. Remove the poster image tag so it looks like this:

`<video autoplay="" loop="" id="video-background">
<source src="http://wp.granitebayit.org/wp-content/themes/gbfbla/images/home.webm" type="video/webm">
</video>`